# Getting the words after a search term using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find the javascript regex to return the string after the word 'the'.

Original string:

```
"The great expedition"
```

I want to return:

```
"great expedition"
```

The closest I have got is:

```
var matched = "The great expedition".match(/^the \b(.*)$/i);
```

matched contains 2 strings in it:

```
["The great expedition", "great expedition"]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Appreciate any help

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT by r3mus]

```
function stripThe(word)
{
    var match = word.match(/^the \b(.*)$/i);
    if (match.length > 1) {
        return match[1];
    }else{
        return word;
    }
}
```

Or, simpler, if you just want to strip it:

```
function stripThe(word)
{
    return word.replace(/^the\s*/i, "");
}
```

This way you only test once for the expression.

Comment: Trouble with this is that if it returns false, it'll throw an index out of range error on `[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for the regex term that will get me that word after 'The', there must be a way to only return the string after using a regular expression

Comment: @ManofSnow yep that's better! You might want to clean up the example though, don't use inline `

Comment: @ManofSnow although, still better to set as a variable so you're not processing the regex twice.

Comment: Cleaned up your code block again -- if that makes sense you can use it (or delete it)

Comment: @ManofSnow no worries! I should too, since my example doesn't actually work properly.. working on fixing it